# How to get Intel Atom Z36xxx/Z37xxx HD Audio working in Alpine?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa, alpine-linux

I've installed Alpine 3.18 on a PC with a Gigabyte J1900N-D2H motherboard. I'm running XFCE, but getting no sound.

There is no volume control icon in the tray area, and no sound options in the menu or the settings.

During my four-hour stint of googling and trying things, I used the terminal to install `alsa-utils` and `alsaconf`; and I did `rc-service alsa start`.

I used `alsamixer` to unmute the relevant channels (several times actually, because for some reason they kept automatically re-muting themselves), after which `speaker-test` actually managed to output something - although it would only output on the front left channel (I have stereo speakers) until I added the arguments `-D default:PCH -c2`.

After a while, I went so far as to install `pulseaudio-utils` in case alsa wasn't the right system. No dice.

I still have no desktop audio. For example, I get no sound on Youtube in Firefox. There is still no volume control in the tray, and no sound settings in the menu. What am I doing wrong?

(I saw one suggestion on google to "recompile the kernel with the correct driver module" but I've never compiled a kernel in my life and wouldn't know how to. Surely that's not the only way to fix this...?)

**EDIT:** I just ran `pulseaudio --start` and installed and ran `pavucontrol`. It defaulted to muted for some reason, but when I unchecked that box I got sound. So I guess Alpine - or Firefox maybe? - expects Pulseaudio and not Alsa?

In any event, why do I still not have a volume icon in the tray; or sound settings in my XFCE menu? Every other distro I've used has had these things.